# Dagger 2 in Unit tests with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

In [Kotlin Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kapt-annotation-processing-for-kotlin/) there is explanation how to make Dagger 2 work with Kotlin.

Everything worked like charm. So far… I just couldn’t make it to work in tests.
`DaggerTestSomeComponent` was not generated from `TestSomeComponent : SomeComponent`.
I’ve tried various combinations. Including creating absolutely new component just in tests. Still nothing.
Is there any workaround or could I provide some other details?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure to add `kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'` to your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, just an addendum In my case I need to use 'kaptTest`